# How to copy records from table and insert into same table using stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table:

[image]

I want to copy only those records which are from version 0 and their student_id is never repeated in version 1, that means unchanged records. and I want to insert all copied records to same table with version 1. What will be stored procedure for this.

Comment: Q: "What will be stored procedure for this". A: "The stored procedure will be one of the possible solutions.". But in all seriousness, you have to show us what you have tried, don't expect free answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `group by` and `having max(version) = 0`:

```
insert into student_name (student_id, student_name, version)
select student_id, max(student_name), 1
from student_name
group by student_id
having max(version) = 0
```

---

As a stored procedure, taking a parameter for `version`, that inserts records for students who do not have a record for that version: and outputs the rows that were inserted:

```
create procedure dbo.insert_new_version (@version int) as
begin;
  set nocount, xact_abort on;

  insert into student_name (student_id, student_name, version)
  output inserted.*
  select 
      student_id
    , student_name = max(student_name)
    , version = @version
  from student_name
  group by student_id
  having max(version) < @version
end;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/JSTNI40605

returns:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------+
| record_id | student_id | student_name | version |
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------+
|        11 |          3 | ccc          |       1 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the records by doing:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.version = 0 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.student_id = t.student_id and t2.version = 1
                 );
```

The rest is just an `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

You can select and insert like this

```
Insert INTO tableName select t1.student_Id, t1.student_name,1 from tablename t1 
where t1.version = 0 and not exists 
(select 1 from tablename  t2 where t2.student_id = t.student_id and t2.version = 1);
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, one should always explain what it does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by LEFT Join:

```
INSERT INTO tbl
SELECT  T1.record_id,T1.student_Id,T1.student_name, 1
FROM    tbl T1 LEFT JOIN tbl    T2
ON  T1.student_Id   =   T2.student_Id AND   T2.version      =   1
WHERE   T1.version  =   0 AND       T2.record_id    IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a while loop to go through the table and identify the items that you need to copy, then these values will be 
evaluated and if they meet the criterion for re-inserting and then insert them.

Your code should look like the following. Add CREATE PROC part and Edit table names where applicable
(Caveat: I have written this on notepad so if you get a few errors, just try to fix them)

```
DECLARE @counter int = 0, @row_Count int = 0, @currentId int,
@currentName nvarchar(100), @version int, @current_Student_id int

SET @row_Count = (SELECT COUNT(record_Id) from yourTable)

WHILE @counter <= @row_Count
BEGIN
SET @currentId = (SELECT record_Id FROM (SELECT row_number() over (order by id) 
            AS RowNum, record_Id  FROM yourTable) sub WHERE RowNum=@counter)

SET @currentName = (SELECT student_name FROM yourTable WHERE record_Id = @currentId)
SET @current_Student_id = (SELECT student_id FROM yourTable WHERE record_Id = @currentId)
SET @version = (SELECT version FROM yourTable WHERE record_Id = @currentId)

--USE IF to check if the current version is 0 and the student ID has not been inserted already

IF (SELECT COUNT(record_Id) FROM yourTable WHERE student_id = @current_Student_id AND version = 1) < 1
            AND @version = 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO yourTable (student_id, student_name, version)
    VALUES
(
@current_Student_id,
@currentName,
1
)
END

SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```